# How to send data between Java and PHP (synchronously)

Tags: java, php, json, rest

I use PHP to generate the front-end, rendering the HTML, running some SQL queries on the database, etc. The SQL queries are becoming slower and slower and the only way to improve them is to make requests non-stateless. Currently, request causes some query to fetch data and return it via JSON to the client, but the improved query (no group by, barely any joins and sorting) would need to hold an object with the results of the previous requests: objects returned, their order, some of their attributes. Knowing what the previously returned objects were, any requests after that can be handled much faster and queries would become much simpler.

The question is: what is the most reliable way of running a Java service, which accepts the request from PHP and returns the results (JSON) synchronously, so that PHP can immediately parse the data and render the page? Would I be safe using JSON REST API over HTTP(S)? Should I look towards sockets? Could I create persistent connections from PHP without having to make a separate module in C?

P.S. The requests will happen between front-end server and Java server. They can be on the same machine or separate machines. Request might need to be load balanced in the future over a Java cluster.

Comment: You can do all the above, what is best for you depends on your requirements.  Perhaps you should start with what appears to you to be simplest. (Only you know what that is)

Comment: There are many ways, but why does it have to be JSON? I performance is really a concern, you might check out binary alternatives. Then again, it depends on your requirements. Also 'the only way to improve them is to make requests non-stateless'. I'm curious what you mean by that, since non-stateless is often a reason of having performance bottlenecks, not the way to solve them.

Comment: We can assume you have already played with database settings and optimized it, right? Like buffer size, partitions, adding indexes where needed etc.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes. I have heavily optimized the query (manually and automatically via free tools) and the database settings. The query requires GROUP BY on two columns from a derived tmp table (which is produced from 9 LEFT JOINs and contains 20K+ rows) and then sorting of the results and only selecting 15 records. No cache can help with this, neither indexes (tmp table can't use them).

Comment: @ErikPragt most of the times, stateless would outperform non-stateless  solution. But in this case, the query has to use a temporary table with 20K+ rows and group it and then sort it, which takes 1.2 seconds on average and since this is executed 10 times per second at peak load, it's causing full CPU load and if the load stays up, the server runs into max_connections limit. Non-stateless, in this case, would mean having a shared pointer between server and client, so the acquired results set (I will be storing 'short' variable) can be easily traversed up and down when needed.